# Allow connection to modem dashboard in pf firewall

Tags: networking, macos, router, firewall, pf

I am using [Murus](https://www.murusfirewall.com/murus/) to manage the rules of my macos pf firewall.

My approach is to block everything by default and allow only what I need. This has worked well so far, with one exception: I cannot seem to connect to the web dashboard of my modem. Every time I try connecting to http://192.168.0.1 in the browser, the connect times out. If I disable Murus, then everything works immediately. But surely, there is a better way to connect to my modem than by disabling my firewall.

In outbound rules, I allow the "web server" service as follows:

```
pass out log (user) proto {udp, tcp} from any to any port {443, 80} flags S/SA keep state
```

I thought this would take care of it, since this is allowing http connections. But, evidently, it is not.

What should I allow for it to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you review what happens in Wireshark – e.g. is the modem replying to you with something that the OS appears to be ignoring due to firewall?

Comment: Thanks @u1686_grawity! I do have wireshark installed, but have never really used it. I can check when I am home, but what exactly will I be looking for?

Comment: First I'd filter for the modem's IP address and see what shows up when trying to visit – e.g. computer sends TCP SYN (will be color-highlighted), modem replies with TCP SYN/ACK, computer doesn't reply at all, modem keeps retrying the same packet until it gives up, which may indicate a firewall issue. (Wireshark sees inbound packets before pf gets to drop them, but OTOH outbound packets go through pf first.) Or, you might see the connection succeed and actual HTTP requests being made, where the modem may be issuing an HTTP redirect to some unexpected URL on an unusual port.

Comment: Ok, I gave that a try and used "ip.addr == 192.168.0.1" as a filter. From the little that I understand, the firewall must really be blocking everything. In the attached file (with just the first 200 filtered packets), the first two lines are what happens when I load 192.168.0.1 with the firewall activated. The moment I deactivate it, 1500 packets show up.
Link: https://extrait.facil.services/?5aa56cf1a4e8840d#4icRSicoNxCWu6VxGWc1yJAz4BsisGnRdoyFrQH9RQZi

Comment: I'm not seeing anything special there; and if you say that not even the _first_ packet shows up, that means your rule isn't allowing anything out for some reason. (That is, it's not any of the weirder things that I was guessing at – it's probably something simpler with the pf ruleset.)

Comment: Yes, the first couple of lines do not seem linked to accessing 192.168.0.1, as they showed up randomly and only twice while I frantically tried to load the page. Then I turned off pf/murus, loaded once and all worked. So it has to be a simple rule and, since all is blocked by default, that makes sense. The question is: what rule should I add to make an exception for local devices or, at least, for 192.168.0.1?